# How long does it take in general to write a CS Ph.D. dissertation?

Tags: phd, thesis

I want to ask about the approximate duration needed to write a CS Ph.D. dissertation in EU?
Or more specifically, when before the end of the Ph.D. program (3 years), most supervisors will advice about starting to write the thesis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German perspective:
It can vary widely between one and twelve months. I assume you will have the required number of papers published and/or under review. Hence, all of the results will already there, most of the text as well.
Then, there are (at least in Germany) two types of theses: monograph (one single work) or commutative (staple your papers together). The first takes more time since you will have to rewrite and replot your content and fuse it all into a single story. For the second you write a long intro and only copy your papers for the actual content.

However, writing is only one part. The thesis has be reviewed and you have the final presentation. Those two things can take many months. Check very carefully with your university and talk with the responsible secretaries. Sometimes there are fixed dates at which you can officially submit the thesis for review. As always, talk with your advisor as well.